# How do I install the latest version of Libre Office?

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice

How can I install the latest version of Libre Office?

If there is more than 1 way, please provide all of them.

Comment: IDK, every time i try to install any thing it says: The following packages have unmet dependencies: google-chrome-stable : Depends: gconf-service Depends: libgconf-2-4 (>= 2.31.1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed libreoffice : Depends: fonts-sil-gentium-basic but it is not going to be installed Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ub

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are 3 ways.

1. From the repositories - (Older version, not recommended):

   To install Libre Office just run this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libreoffice
   ```

   or open Software Centre and search for "Libre Office".
2. From an official PPA:

   This PPA is for version 5.0.X (Recommended):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-0
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install libreoffice
   ```

   Note: The above PPA provides Libre Office 5.0.X updates. If Libre Office 5.1.X released then we need to use another PPA.

   For any version we can use the `ppa:libreoffice/ppa PPA`:

   LibreOffice X.X.X (Fresh, Latest version - not for production environment):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install libreoffice
   ```
3. From the website, using the `.deb` files (No auto-update, not recommended):

   First, visit the Download page. To jump to the `.deb` version for [64 bit click here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86&version=5.0.3&lang=en-GB), or for [32 bit click here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86&version=5.0.3&lang=en-GB).

   Next, click Download. Consider using the Torrent file as it reduces the load on their servers.

   When the 229 MB download is finished (which will take 9.5 hours on dial up or 7 minutes on a High Speed T3 connection) you will need to extract the `.tar.gz` file.

   Navigate to the file in your file manager, right click and chose "Extract Here".

   Open a terminal and run this command:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/LibreOffice5*/DEBS
   ```

   Then, as the `README` says you need to run this command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   This will take a while, but when the command finishes, you will have Libre Office 5.0

Comment: umm Why is the latest version ppa not recommended? Is it not stable?

Comment: @Tim can you answer ^  ?

Comment: @Adityaultra edited post :) Tim feel free to edit again if needed

Comment: @Adityaultra that one is intended for devs and bug finders. It's stable but not for a production environment

Comment: will the `libreoffice-5-0` ppa ensure updates above 5.0? the ubuntu repo already gives 5.1 in 2018.04, while the latest is 6.0.3